# make socat open port only on localhost interface

Tags: interface, localhost, socat

I use this line to open a connection to a server through a socks proxy:

```
socat -v TCP4-LISTEN:77,fork SOCKS4A:44.44.44.44:33.33.33.33:99,socksport=9898
```

it works great but I noticed it also opens the port 77 externally (like: 192.168.1.100:77). I would like it to only open it on 127.0.0.1:77.

PS. I do not want to have to configure firewall to block the port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is

```
socat -v TCP4-LISTEN:77,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 SOCKS4A:44.44.44.44:33.33.33.33:99,socksport=9898
```